# JSRender : Recursive Call to Parent Template

Tags: javascript, recursion, jsrender

I have use-case wherein the input json can have n number of nested child objects and for that I want to display tree structure. Probably need to have some sort of a recursive rendering logic to achieve this. I am new to jsrender so can someone please help me with a sample code for my scenario.

Sample JSON which needs to be worked on:

> {
> "id": "1",
> "keys": [
> {
> "name": "test1",
> "values": [
> {
> "param_name": "abc"
> },
> {
> "param_name": "def",
> "childObjects": [
> {
> "actualvalue": "a1",
> "t2": "a2",
> "t3": "a3",
> "childObject": [
> {
> "actualvalue": "a1",
> "t2": "a2",
> "t3": "a3"
> }
> ]
> },
> {
> "actualvalue": "a4",
> "t5": "a5",
> "t6": "a6"
> }
> ]
> }
> ]
> }
> ]
> }

```
<script id="theContent" type="text/x-jsrender">
<div class="sec sec-middle">
{{for keys}}
{{for values}}
{{if childObjects}}
{^{tree/}}
{{/if}}
{{/for}}
{{/for}}
</div>
</script>
```

And the tree-if.js is as below:

```
    (function($) {
  "use strict";
  $.views.tags({
      tree: {
        template: '<div class="param-list parm-accord-level-one">' +
        '<div class="param-top-list">' +
            '<div class="parm-col parm-heading">' +
                '<a href="javscritp:void(0);" class="parm-accordion-title"><strong>{{:param_name}}</strong> <i class="far fa-angle-down"></i></a>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="parm-col parm-description">' +
                '<span class="btn grey-btn string-btn">{{:data_type}}</span><span class="normal-text">{{:description}}</span>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="parm-accordion-details">' +
            '<div class="tree-sec">' +
                '{{for childObjects}}' +
                    '{{if childObjects}}' +
                      '{{tree/}}' +
                    '{{else}}' +
                    '<div class="param-list">' +
                        '<div class="param-top-list">' +
                            '<div class="parm-col parm-heading">' +
                                '<span>{{:child_param_name}}</span>' +
                                '{{if isMandatory}}' +
                                    '<span class="seconday-text mandatory-text">mandatory</span>' +
                                '{{/if}}' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="parm-col parm-description">' +
                                '<span class="btn grey-btn string-btn">{{:child_data_type}}</span>' +
                                '<span class="string-text">{{:child_description}}</span>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '{{/if}}' +
                '{{/for}}' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +    
    '</div>'
      }
    });
  })(this.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some samples which illustrate recursive rendering of a hierarchical structure":

[A JsViews "tree" tag control](https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/tree)

And also [this "jsonview" tag control sample](https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/jsonview), which is interactive, using JsViews, but a similar approach could be used just with JsRender.

Comment: Hey I tried the given example but getting an error as ''l {name: 'JsViews Error', message: 'Unknown tag: {{tree}} '}". I have updated the question itself with the sample code which I tried. Please correct me if I am missing out something. Note: I am using js-render.

Comment: In JsRender you can write {{tree/}}, rather than {^{tree}}. If it says tree is an unknown tag, then you must have not loaded the tag definition prior to calling the render code.

Comment: I have included the tree-if.js in the render jsp page. Is there anything else which needs to be done?

Comment: I don't use JSP. But you don't need to have the tag definition code  `$.views.tags({tree: {...}})` in a separate file. You can simply insert it directly before the call to `var html = $("#theContent").render(yourData);`. That way it is loaded before the render() call.
You don't need to wrap it in `(function($) {...})(this.jQuery);`